# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensure_future'

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, asyncsocket, python-asyncio

Hi i am writing a n/w bound server application using python asyncio which can accept a post request.

In post request i am accepting a symbol parameter

please tell me the best way to deal with n/w bound application.where i am collecting the data from another web api's by sending the post request to them.

Following is the code :

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
import logging

# async def fetch_content(url, symbols):
# yield from  aiohttp.post(url, symbols=symbols)

@asyncio.coroutine
def fetch_page(writer, url, data):
   response = yield from aiohttp.post(url, data=data)
   resp = yield from response.read_and_close()
   print(resp)
   writer.write(resp) 
   return           


@asyncio.coroutine
def process_payload(writer, data, scale):
   tasks = []
   data = data.split('\r\n\r\n')[1]
   data = data.split('\n')
   data = [x.split(':') for x in data]
   print(data)
   data = {x[0]: x[1] for x in data}
   print(data)                 
   # data = data[0].split(':')[1]
   data = data['symbols']
   print(data)
   data = data.split(',')
   data_len = len(data)
   data_first = 0
   data_last = scale
   url = 'http://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxx'
   while data_last < data_len:
       tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_page(writer, url,{'symbols': ",".join(data[data_first:data_last])})))
       data_first += scale
       data_last += scale 

   tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_page(writer, url,{'symbols': ",".join(data[data_first:data_last])})))
   loop.run_until_complete(tasks)    
   return 

@asyncio.coroutine
def process_url(url):
    pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def echo_server():
  yield from asyncio.start_server(handle_connection, 'xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx', 3000)

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_connection(reader, writer):
   data = yield from reader.read(8192)

   if data:
        message =  data.decode('utf-8')
        print(message)
        yield from process_payload(writer, message, 400)

   writer.write_eof()   
   writer.close()


#url = 'http://XXXXXXX.xxxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxx'
data = {'symbols': 'GD-US,14174T10,04523Y10,88739910,03209R10,46071F10,77543110,92847N10'}

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(echo_server())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

But i am receiving the following error:

```
future: <Task finished coro=<handle_connection() done, defined at        fql_server_async_v2.py:53> exception=AttributeError("'module' object has no   attribute 'ensure_future'",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/anugupta/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 234, in _step
result = coro.send(value)
File "fql_server_async_v2.py", line 60, in handle_connection
yield from process_payload(writer, message, 400)
File "/home/user/anugupta/lib/python3.4/asyncio/coroutines.py", line 141, in coro
res = func(*args, **kw)
File "fql_server_async_v2.py", line 41, in process_payload
tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_page(writer, url,  {'symbols':",".join(data[data_first:data_last])})))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ensure_future'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "fql_server_async_v2.py", line 72, in <module>
loop.run_forever()
File "/home/user/anugupta/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 236,  in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "/home/user/anugupta/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1017, in _run_once
event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
File "/home/user/anugupta/lib/python3.4/selectors.py", line 424, in select
fd_event_list = self._epoll.poll(timeout, max_ev)
```

Comment: when i am sending a large amount of data through post request for symbol parameter ,it is unable to read the whole data at once . so in case of bulk data it is receiving empty data ,please tell me the best way to read bulk data from post request

Comment: [asyncio.ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) appears in version 3.4.4, I guess you're running an older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ensure_future` was added in *asyncio 3.4.4*, use `async` for earlier versions.

While `async` is deprecated now it will be supported in oversable future.

Comment: hi andrew can u suggest me some way to read a bulk data from post request . data = {symbols= '56633010,17290810,41308610,05945F10,51384710,74838J10,45168K30'}  here symbols contain more then 20000 values (comma separated ) , here data = yield from reader.read(8192) is giving empty data if symbols contain more then 200 values . please suggest me way to write a bulk data which i am receiving as a response from another web api to the writer.